# Computing a limit with assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

This program solves the recurrence for the expected time to extinction of a linear birth and death process with arrival rate A and death rate q A, and then attempts to simplify.

```
t = a[n] /. 
   RSolve[{A n  a[n + 1] - A (1 + q) n  a[n] + q A  n  a[n - 1] + 1 == 0, 
     a[0] == 0, a[K] == 0}, a[n], n] // FullSimplify
```

But, Mathematica refuses to simplify, the answer contains `-(1/q)^K q^K`.
Then, I want to compute a limit with Assumptions.

```
Limit[t, K -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {K > 0, A>0, 0 < q < 1}]
```

But Mathematica refuses, and cannot compute the limit

```
Limit::alimv: Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored.
```

Is it possible to do better?

---

The  answer is yes! as shown by the repliers, who proved the infinite limit which is a consequence of the fact that one of my assumptions  was wrong (or not capable of producing finite limits).  The following code incorporates now the suggestions and resolves the case q>1 (death rate bigger than birth rate), when the limit is finite

```
t = a[n] /. 
   RSolve[{A n  a[n + 1] - A (1 + q) n  a[n] + q A  n  a[n - 1] + 1 == 0, 
     a[0] == 0, a[K] == 0}, a[n], n][[1]] // FullSimplify[#, {K > 0, A > 0, 0 < q }] &
```

Then, I want to compute a limit with Assumptions. The case when it should be finite is the opposite of what I had asked, ie q>1

```
Limit[t, K -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {K > 0, A>0,  q > 1,n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

But, this is still too hard, so we break into pieces. The middle term

```
a2=Limit[(-1 + q^K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n]/(A (-1 + q) q (-1 + q^K)), 
 K -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, q > 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

yields finite

```
a2=LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n]/(A (-1 + q) q)
```

The last term

```
a3 = Limit[
  q ((1 - q^n) HarmonicNumber[K] + (-1 + q^K) HarmonicNumber[
        n] + (q^K - q^n) Log[(-1 + q)/q])/(A (-1 + q) q (-1 + q^K)), 
  K -> Infinity, 
  Assumptions -> {A > 0, q > 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

also is finite

```
(HarmonicNumber[n] + Log[(-1 + q)/q])/(A (-1 + q))
```

The first term is too hard on my computer, but

```
a1 = DiscreteLimit[-((-1 + q^n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K])/(A (-1 + 
        q) q (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity, 
   Assumptions -> {A > 0, q > 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}] // 
  FullSimplify
```

yields 0. When n=1, the sum a2 + a3 simplifies to
Log[q/(q-1)])/A, a result of Whittle 1955. Magic!

Comment: `Limit[-(1/q)^k*q^k, k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {0 < q < 1}]` works fine so this is not the problem.

Comment: If we simplify your expression: `A = 1/2; q = 
 1/2; R = (RSolveValue[{A n a[n + 1] - A (1 + q) n a[n] + 
        q A n a[n - 1] + 1 == 0, a[0] == 0, a[k] == 0}, a[n], n] /. 
    n -> 1 // FullSimplify); Plot[R // Re, {k, 0, 10000}]` plot looks like a `log function` then if  `k->Infinty`  then : `a[n]->Infinity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mariusz Iwaniuk's guess can be grounded in such a way.

First, somewhat improving your `t` (`Limit` works better with an expression than a list.), we put

```
t = Expand[a[n] /. RSolve[{A n a[n + 1] - A (1 + q) n a[n] + q A n a[n - 1] + 
    1 == 0, a[0] == 0, a[K] == 0}, a[n], n][[1]]]
```

> `(EulerGamma q^K)/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - (EulerGamma q^n)/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) + ((1/q)^K q^(-1 + K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - ((1/q)^K q^(-1 + K + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - ((1/q)^n q^(-1 + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) + ((1/q)^n q^(-1 + K + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) + ( q^K Log[1 - 1/q])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - (q^n Log[1 - 1/q])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) + PolyGamma[0, 1 + K]/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - (q^n PolyGamma[0, 1 + K])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - PolyGamma[0, 1 + n]/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) + (q^K PolyGamma[0, 1 + n])/( A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K))`

I think (pay your attention to the assumption on `n`)

```
Limit[t, K -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

is too hard for `Limit` so we do it step by step (Two small steps are better than one big step.)

```
Limit[(EulerGamma q^K)/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity, 
Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `0`

```
Limit[-((EulerGamma q^n)/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K))), K -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `(EulerGamma q^n)/(A (-1 + q))`

Now we face a difficulty.

```
Limit[((1/q)^k q^(-1 + K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity,  Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

returns the input. Fortunately,

```
FullSimplify[DiscreteLimit[((1/q)^k q^(-1 + K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K])/
(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity, 
Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}],
Assumptions -> { 0 < q < 1]
```

> `0`

The same issue with

```
DiscreteLimit[-(((1/q)^K q^(-1+K+n) LerchPhi[1/q,1,1+K])/(A (-1+q) (-1+q^K))),K->Infinity,Assumptions->{A>0,0<q<1,n\[Element]PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `(q^(-1 + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, \[Infinity]])/(A (-1 + q))`

No problem with the next  items.

```
Limit[-(((1/q)^n q^(-1 + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n])/
(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K))), K -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n]/(A (-1 + q) q)`

```
Limit[((1/q)^n q^(-1 + K + n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n])/
(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}
```

> `0`

```
Limit[(q^k Log[1 - 1/q])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^k)) - 
( q^n Log[1 - 1/q])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^k)), k -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `(q^n (I \[Pi] + Log[-1 + 1/q]))/(A (-1 + q))`

The infinite limit is caused by

```
Limit[PolyGamma[0, 1 + K]/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - 
(q^n PolyGamma[0, 1 + K])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) - 
PolyGamma[0, 1 + n]/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)) +
 (q^K PolyGamma[0, 1 + n])/(A (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)), K -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

> `(-1+q^n) (-\[Infinity])`

Therefore, summarizing the above, we conclude that

```
DiscreteLimit[t, K -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

is infinite. This implies

```
Limit[t, K -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {A > 0, 0 < q < 1, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

is infinite or indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" )

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Include the assumptions in the initial [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)

```
t = a[n] /. 
   RSolve[{A n a[n + 1] - A (1 + q) n a[n] + q A n a[n - 1] + 1 == 0, 
      a[0] == 0, a[K] == 0}, a[n], n][[1]] // 
  FullSimplify[#, {K > 0, A > 0, 0 < q < 1}] &

(* (-((-1 + q^n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K]) + (-1 + q^K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n] + 
   q ((1 - q^n) HarmonicNumber[K] + (-1 + q^K) HarmonicNumber[
        n] + (q^K - q^n) Log[(-1 + q)/q]))/(A (-1 + q) q (-1 + q^K)) *)
```

Use [`Asymptotic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html) (introduced in v12.1, updated in v13.2) for the behavior as `K -> Infinity`

```
largeK = Asymptotic[t, K -> Infinity] // 
  FullSimplify[#, {K > 0, A > 0, 0 < q < 1}] &

(* (-((1 + 2 EulerGamma K) q (-1 + q^n)) + 2 K q (-1 + q^K) HarmonicNumber[n] - 
   2 K (-1 + q^n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K] + 
   2 K ((-1 + q^K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n] + 
      q (Log[K] + q^K Log[(-1 + q)/q] - 
         q^n Log[(K (-1 + q))/q])))/(2 A K (-1 + q) q (-1 + q^K)) *)
```

Comment: Your latest result `(-((1 + 2 EulerGamma K) q (-1 + q^n)) + 2 K q (-1 + q^K) HarmonicNumber[n] -     2 K (-1 + q^n) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + K] +     2 K ((-1 + q^K) LerchPhi[1/q, 1, 1 + n] +        q (Log[K] + q^K Log[(-1 + q)/q] -           q^n Log[(K (-1 + q))/q])))/(2 A K (-1 + q) q (-1 + q^K))`  mostly  or completely repeats `t`, is not so?

Comment: Indeed, `Simplify[t - largeK]` results in `(1/(2 A K (-1 + q) (-1 + q^K)))(-1 - 2 EulerGamma K + q^n + 
  2 EulerGamma K q^n - 2 K (-1 + q^n) HarmonicNumber[K] - 
  2 K Log[K] - 2 K q^n Log[(-1 + q)/q] + 2 K q^n Log[(K (-1 + q))/q])`.